How to make a left join that the keys can have multiple granularity with Spark?
I have this sample table that represents the salary of all company's employees:



PLANT
DEPTO
NAME
SALARIES




1
MG
KEVIN
1.100


2
SP
ETHAN
1.200


3
DF
JUAN
1.200


4
SP
BETH
110


5
SP
JOHN
1.000



And also have this other table that represents the increase that need to be apply in the salaries:



INCREASE_ID
PLANT
DEPTO
NAME
FACTOR




IC1
1
MG

1.2


IC2
2
SP

1.4


IC3
3
DF

1.3


IC4
4
SP
BETH
1.3


IC5

SP

1.02



Increases can be applied cumulatively and if one of the keys match. As an example, Ethan can get two types of raises combined:

IC2: Because PLANT = 2 and DEPTO = SP
IC5: Because DEPTO = SP

With this in mind, my goal is to get the following table when above two are combined:



PLANT
DEPTO
NAME
VALUE
LIST_OF_INCREASE_ID
FACTOR_COMBINED




1
MG
KEVIN
1.100
IC1
1,20


2
SP
ETHAN
1.200
IC2 and IC5
1,43 (1,4 * 1,02)


3
MG
JUAN
1.200

1,00


4
SP
BETH
1.300
IC4 and IC5
1,33 (1,3 * 1,02)


5
SP
JOHN
1.000
IC5
1,02



Does anyone have any suggestions for a method or join type that can "avoid" these null cases when I have a match in any of the key columns (PLANT, DEPTO or NAME)?

I think it's a two left join, first by the PLANT and second by DEPTO? For left join, even there is no matched key, the null columns will still exist.

@Jonathan could be a way, but the main problem here is the fact that I need to apply increases in the salaries not just by one or two key columns... This needs to be applied by the combination of these Keys columns... in the end, sometimes I can do it by name, by depto or plant, or the combination of them. This is a lot o possibilities.

I found this way to make joins "conditionally", that can "avoid" nulls... I'm working on it to see if it works in my case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70890880/pyspark-join-with-null-values-in-right-dataset

For future readers who have the same problem, I was able to solve it by following the conditional join idea described in this post.
Basically, I created a variable that store the conditions that replace each null value with the corresponding one in the fact table, obtaining the following table:
# make condition to join increase_df and fact_df

condition = (
   (fn.coalesce(increase_df.PLANT, fact_df.PLANT) == fact_df.PLANT) &
   (fn.coalesce(increase_df.DEPTO, fact_df.DEPTO) == fact_df.DEPTO) &
   (fn.coalesce(increase_df.NAME, fact_df.NAME) == fact_df.NAME)
)

final_df = (
    fact_df
    .join(increase_df, condition, "left")
)

final_df.show()
+-----+-----+-----+------+-----------+-----+-----+----+------+
|PLANT|DEPTO| NAME| VALUE|INCREASE_ID|PLANT|DEPTO|NAME|FACTOR|
+-----+-----+-----+------+-----------+-----+-----+----+------+
|    1|   MG|KEVIN|1100.0|        IC1|    1|   MG|null|   1.2|
|    2|   SP|ETHAN|1200.0|        IC5| null|   SP|null|  1.02|
|    2|   SP|ETHAN|1200.0|        IC2|    2|   SP|null|   1.4|
|    3|   DF| JUAN|1200.0|        IC3|    3|   DF|null|   1.3|
|    4|   SP| BETH|1100.0|        IC5| null|   SP|null|  1.02|
|    4|   SP| BETH|1100.0|        IC4|    4|   SP|BETH|   1.3|
|    5|   SP| JOHN|1000.0|        IC5| null|   SP|null|  1.02|
+-----+-----+-----+------+-----------+-----+-----+----+------+

After that, I just made aggregations of the values:
+-----+-----+-----+------+------+-----------+
|PLANT|DEPTO| NAME| VALUE|FACTOR|INCREASE_ID|
+-----+-----+-----+------+------+-----------+
|    1|   MG|KEVIN|1100.0|   1.2|        IC1|
|    2|   SP|ETHAN|1200.0| 1.428|IC5 and IC2|
|    3|   DF| JUAN|1200.0|   1.3|        IC3|
|    4|   SP| BETH|1100.0| 1.326|IC5 and IC4|
|    5|   SP| JOHN|1000.0|  1.02|        IC5|
+-----+-----+-----+------+------+-----------+

